# Why is my for loop code slower than an iterator?

Tags: performance, rust

I am trying to solve the leetcode problem [distribute-candies](https://leetcode.com/problems/distribute-candies). It is easy, just find out the minimum between the candies' kinds and candies half number.

Here's my solution (cost 48ms):

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub fn distribute_candies(candies: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    let sister_candies = (candies.len() / 2) as i32;
    let mut kind = 0;
    let mut candies_kinds = HashSet::new();
    for candy in candies.into_iter() {
        if candies_kinds.insert(candy) {
            kind += 1;
            if kind > sister_candies {
                return sister_candies;
            }
        }
    }
    kind
}
```

However, I found a solution using an iterator:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::cmp::min;

pub fn distribute_candies(candies: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    min(candies.iter().collect::<HashSet<_>>().len(), candies.len() / 2) as i32
}
```

and it costs 36ms.

I can't quite understand why the iterator solution is faster than my `for` loop solution. Are there some magic optimizations that Rust is performing in the background?

Comment: Your code creates a `HashSet` with zero capacity, and then has to reallocate every time the actual size doubles. The iterator version can use the size hint from the vector iterator to allocate the correct size to the `HashSet`. You can make your code do the same by using `HashSet::with_capacity(candies.len())` instead of `HashSet::new()`.

Comment: Have you considered sorting first? It's O(N log N), but would avoid memory allocation altogether and possibly be more cache friendly, which may give better performance. Once sorted, a simple linear pass over the data will easily let you know how many kinds there are.

Comment: @MatthieuM. This might be faster, but I don't know how to benchmark it. It mutates the original data, so that needs to be copied for each iteration of the bencher.

Comment: @E4_net_or_something_like_that: The current signature takes the `Vec` by copy anyway...

Comment: Right. But to test them properly, the data generation shouldn't be included in the benchmark. Would be nice if there was a before/after hook on the bench runner.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I made [a benchmark that clones each iteration](https://gist.github.com/peterjoel/00ea232e48f50b7ff76736ae759ed65b). Sorting the vector is actually slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that the iterator version [internally uses](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#3100-3113) [`Iterator::size_hint`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.size_hint) to determine how much space to reserve in the `HashSet` before collecting into it. This prevents repeatedly having to reallocate as the set grows.

You can do the same using `HashSet::with_capacity` instead of `HashSet::new`:

```
let mut candies_kinds = HashSet::with_capacity(candies.len());
```

In my benchmark this single change makes your code significantly faster than the iterator. However, if I simplify your code to remove the early bailout optimisation, it runs in almost exactly the same time as the iterator version.

```
pub fn distribute_candies(candies: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let sister_candies = (candies.len() / 2) as i32;
    let mut candies_kinds = HashSet::with_capacity(candies.len());
    for candy in candies.into_iter() {
        candies_kinds.insert(candy);
    }
    sister_candies.min(candies_kinds.len() as i32)
}
```

Timings:

```
test tests::bench_iter                          ... bench:     262,315 ns/iter (+/- 23,704)
test tests::bench_loop                          ... bench:     307,697 ns/iter (+/- 16,119)
test tests::bench_loop_with_capacity            ... bench:     112,194 ns/iter (+/- 18,295)
test tests::bench_loop_with_capacity_no_bailout ... bench:     259,961 ns/iter (+/- 17,712)
```

This suggests to me that the `HashSet` preallocation is the dominant difference. Your additional optimisation also proves to be very effective - at least with the dataset that I happened to choose.

Comment: Thanks! I just updated my solution with `HashSet::with_capacity`, and it now cost 32ms against 48ms!

Comment: @bayinamy Are you compiling with `--release`. Those times in milliseconds sound very slow.

Comment: Sorry, 32ms comes from Leetcode online judge, don't know how it compiles.